# In a DataFrame with a sorted, numeric index with duplicates, create a shifted version of existing column and interpolated missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, feature-selection

Having such a Pandas DataFrame `df` with a sorted, numeric index (representing f.e. time or distance) with possible duplicate values:

```
     a    b
  0  4.0  1.0
1.5  5.5  2.5
1.5  5.5  2.5
  2  6.0  3.0
4.5  8.5  5.5
```

I would like to create a column `c`, with values from column `a` with index shifts that are matching the original index. All index shifts that are not matching the original index should be still taken into account when filling in the original index values that did not get the value assigned, using f.e. linear interpolation.

Example:

Taking 0.5 as an example index shift, column `c` would be constructed from column `a` with index values of 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5 and 5, giving the following intermediate result with the missing values marked below as `(i)`:

```
      c
  0  Nan(i)
0.5  4.0
1.5  4.75(i)
  2  5.5
2.5  6.0
4.5  7.25(i)
  5  8.5
```

The final result should be indexed using the original indexes used in `df`:

```
     a    b    c
  0  4.0  1.0  Nan(i)
1.5  5.5  2.5  4.75(i)
1.5  5.5  2.5  4.75(i)
  2  6.0  3.0  5.5
4.5  8.5  5.5  7.25(i)
```

There is a question how to take the value for the duplicate index, in this example one value was chosen, but a mean might be a better appraoch.

Comment: I would like to use the interpolation to fill in the missing values. So far I am trying to construct the Series based on column `a` with combined index values, but the values are placed in old index values, not the shifted ones.

Comment: The goal is to keep the index as is in the original `df` and use interpolation in the intermediate step to fill in the original index values, as not all of them will be present in the shift. In the example above, only index 2 is present in the shift.

Comment: In the example above there are 4 actual values and 3 missing values that I would like to interpolate and bring to the resulting `df`.

Comment: Filling in the missing values in secondary in this question - it can be linear interpolation, backward fill, forward fill, all are fine. What I am looking for is a good approach towards constructing a new column with a described shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is my current approach](https://gist.github.com/krzysztof-slowinski/66d5fd123d7af14261347d7517d46192) that takes one of the duplicate index values into account when constructing a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def create_shift(df, column, shift_value, method, name):
    """
    Create a new column based on an existing column with a given shift value. 
    The shifted column is indexed based on an existing index with the
    missing values interpolated using the given method.

    :param df:          DataFrame to create the shift in.
    :param column:      The column name.
    :param shift_value: The value to shift the existing column by.
    :param method:      The interpolation method.
    :param name:        The name used for the newly created column.
    """
    if column in df.columns:
        current_index = df.index
        # creating the shifted index with the 2 decimal point precision
        shift_index = [round(i + shift_value, 2) for i in current_index.values]
        shift_data = pd.Series(data=df[column].tolist(), index=shift_index)
        # removing possible duplicates
        shift_data = shift_data[~shift_data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
        shift_index = shift_data.index
        missing_index = current_index.difference(shift_index)
        combined_index = pd.Index(np.append(shift_index, missing_index)).sort_values()
        combined_data = shift_data.reindex(combined_index)
        combined_data.interpolate(method=method, inplace=True)
        df[name] = combined_data
    else:
        print("[Warning] Cannot create shift {} for missing {} column...".format(name, column))


d1 = {'a': [4.0, 5.5, 5.5, 6.0, 8.5], 'b': [1.0, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 5.5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, index=[0, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 4.5])
create_shift(df1, 'a', 0.5, 'linear', 'c')
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is, what you try to achieve:

```
#define the shift value
index_shift = 0.5
#find values common to both indices before and after the shift
ind_intersect = df.index.intersection(df.index + index_shift)
#create new column
df["c"] = np.nan
#transfer values from column a to column c
df["c"][ind_intersect] = df["a"][ind_intersect - index_shift]
```

You can of course fill your new column with other values than numpy `NaN`.

Comment: It is a good solution, but not all values are taken for filling in the missing values, only the ones that after the shift are contained in the original index. The original index is not evenly spaced and there are any shift values possible, so in the worst case no values will be present.

Comment: Please check the description with the intermediate step for calculating the result.

Comment: I've updated the description to better capture the idea of the problem.